# Debug a console_script with pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a complex python program I'd like to debug where the setup.py has

```
 entry_points=dict(
      console_scripts=[
          'myprog = myprog.command:myprog_main',
      ]
  )
```

where the command.py has the logic to accept command so I can run something like

```
myprog process --config config.yaml
```

Placing a breakingpoint in pycharm doesn't cause the program to stop, since doing `python command.py process --config config.yaml` doesn't do anything

I feel this something basic, but I couldn't find a way to debug this (using pycharm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take `jupyter notebook` as an example:

In `jupyter`, it `from jupyter_core.command import main`, so what I need to do is placing a breakpoint in `jupyter_core.command:main`.

And then, I need to add a configuration in Pycharm. `Script path` should be `/path/to/jupyter`, `Parameters` should be `notebook`.

Next, I need to click `Debug`.

I've done, I reach the breakpoint in `jupyter_core.command:main`.

Answer (score 1):

In case [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831090/3702319) doesn't work for you, try this:

1. add a run configuration in PyCharm
2. configure it with *Module name* instead of *Script path*.

   [image]
3. Set the *Module name* to `myprog.command`
4. Add the following section to `myprog/command.py`:

   ```py
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       myprog_main()
   ```

   Sadly, setting the *Module name* to `myprog.command:myprog_main` doesn't work.
5. Set the *Working directory* to the root of your repo (i.e. the parent of the module `myprog` such that the imports work).

*Note*: I used the exact names from OP's question. Please adjust the names of functions, modules, and packages for your problem accordingly.